# How to add a new business object to Universal Search in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have been able to add additional search fields to existing entities in the universal search of Acumatica.  However, adding a similar definition to NoteID on a custom table does not add the object to the Rebuild Full-Text Entity Index screen and does not make the custom data searchable.

I added a one-to-many list of selectable attributes to my Stock Items screen, and the values need to be included in the universal search.  The syntax on the NoteID field looks identical to other source code, and the code compiles cleanly.

It appears the entities to be included are returned by PXSearchableAttribute.GetAllSearchableEntities(), but it does not appear to be in source code to see how this works.  Are the entities fixed, or can I add my own for universal search?

How do I get data from my custom table to be searchable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-Text Entity Index requires the entity to have a `NoteID` field, decorated with the usual `PXNote` attribute as well as `PXSearchable`. Here's an example coming from the `APInvoice` DAC:

```
    [PXSearchable(SM.SearchCategory.AP, "AP {0}: {1} - {3}", new Type[] { typeof(APInvoice.docType), typeof(APInvoice.refNbr), typeof(APInvoice.vendorID), typeof(Vendor.acctName) },
        new Type[] { typeof(APInvoice.invoiceNbr), typeof(APInvoice.docDesc)},
        NumberFields = new Type[] { typeof(APInvoice.refNbr) },
        Line1Format = "{0:d}{1}{2}", Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(APInvoice.docDate), typeof(APInvoice.status), typeof(APInvoice.invoiceNbr) },
        Line2Format = "{0}", Line2Fields = new Type[] { typeof(APInvoice.docDesc) },
        MatchWithJoin = typeof(InnerJoin<Vendor, On<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<APInvoice.vendorID>>>),
        SelectForFastIndexing = typeof(Select2<APInvoice, InnerJoin<Vendor, On<APInvoice.vendorID, Equal<Vendor.bAccountID>>>>)
    )]
    [PXNote(ShowInReferenceSelector = true)]
    public override Guid? NoteID
```

The `GetAllSearchableEntities` function does nothing more than looping through every table using `ServiceManager.TableList`, and looking for note fields that are decorated with the expected attributes. The table list is cached on application startup, so depending on how you published your changes a reload may not have been completed. If you have already configured your field as described above, you could try doing `iisreset` from the command-line to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I had copied similar code and adjusted it, but my field came in to the DLC as Noteid which I assume was a case sensitive issue.  Once I changed it to NoteID, republished, and did iisreset as you suggested, it appeared in the Rebuild Full-Text Entity Index screen as expected!  Thank you for your assistance! (I would +1 this if I could, but I'm still too new here.)